# Why the location is being repeated on my PWA with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, progressive-web-apps

I have a problem to get the location of my PWA's users. The location that is being taken are repeated and is not being updated.

```
$("#storeLocation").click(function () {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function (e) {
      a = e.coords.latitude + "," + e.coords.longitude; 

      // HERE I STORE THE COORDS IN MY DATABASE
    },
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: Infinity, maximumAge: 0 }
  );
});
```

The button is working because I could see that when I click on it is storing the location, but is storing always the same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continually monitor the user's location, use the Geolocation API method, [`watchPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition). It works in the same way, except it will fire multiple times as the location of the user changes, or gets more accurate.

```js
$("#storeLocation").click(() => {
  const posOpts = { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: Infinity, maximumAge: 0 };
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((e) => {
    const position = a = e.coords.latitude + "," + e.coords.longitude;
    // Store position here
  }, posOpts);
});
```